# SETX PATH equivalent on Mac

Tags: r, windows, macos-mojave

I'm a mac newbie and also not really experienced with using the terminal etc. 
I'm using macOS Mojave version 10.14.5 and R 3.6.1

I'm trying to run a R script with the terminal. Unfortunately, the tutorial is only for Windows.

In the beginning the tutorial says: 
type the command SETX EWASTE_SCRIPT_PATH "[FOLDER SCRIPT PATH]" and enter the location of the folder with the scripts between the "". Right-click and choose paste, to paste this location that was copied to the clipboard before. The command would then look for instance like this: SETX EWASTE_SCRIPT_PATH "F:\Vincent\Documents\ewaste-master\scripts".

My question was, what code I would need to do the same on a mac.

Edit: The solution is to set the system environment variables from within Rshell by using Sys.setenv, for example:

```
Sys.setenv(EWASTE_SCRIPT_PATH="/Users/name/desktop/ewaste-master/scripts")
```

and then run the script directly from the Rshell:

```
source("/Users/name/desktop/ewaste-master/scripts/main.R")
```

Comment: Is this tutorial for some package? This doesn't look like normal "R" stuff. Have you tried using `Sus.setenv` to get the variable? When you update your bash_profile, are you logging out and back in again to actually trigger the code to run?

Comment: The tutorial is not for some package but for collecting data from statistical data bases: github.com/Statistics-Netherlands/ewaste. And yes, `sys.setenv` really helps to solve the problem. Thank you!